# Failed to push refs on a multi-user GIT Server

Tags: git, permissions, readonly, refs

I am using GIT for versioning for me and my co-worker, and since the beginning
I am running into an error that randomly effects either me or my co-worker.

We have two different users that push/pull to our Git-Server. Both are members of the same group **gitusers**.

From time to time (not all the time), if one of us pushes his changes to the server, the other gets an: **ERROR: failed to push some ref to ''**
Changes were of course pulled before.

If found out that the permission for **.git/refs/HEADS/[PROJECT_NAME]** changed from **rw-rw-r** 
to **rw-r-r** so **readonly** for other group members. Owner is the last user who successfully pushed to the server.

I don't understand why. Especially because it does not happen all the time.

Can someone offer any advice?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Found the problem.
Problem was the type of repository I set up.

The gitserver project has to be a **shared** and a **bare** repository.
You can convert an existing repo easily.

No more refs errors!